# Android how to achieve this listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I am building an application and I want to make a listview like the one in the following picture. The number of items that are displayed in every line changes depending on the device's orientation (2 vertically, 1 horizontally)

[image]

Is it something that Android provides or how could I implement this? I dont know how to search for it.

Comment: Use a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: That doesn't look like a listview, grid maybe

Comment: that are cardviews http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Recyclerview with GridView for this. First get orientation by `

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`
```

Then set gridview layout for recyclerview and

`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));`

Here 2 will set two vertical lines.you can set span size according to your need.